# java RuntimeExceptions and Errors

Tags: java, runtimeexception

According to "Sams Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days" book

> "Unchecked exceptions, also called runtime exceptions..."

Under that fact,Error are also runtime exception as they are unchecked exceptions( or is it not what it says?)

This confuses me with the below statement.

> Run Time Exceptions are internal errors in the Java run time
>   environment.

If it talks about java RuntimeExceptions then,it's false because they are Exceptions which are described as "Exception describes errors caused by your program and external circumstances. These errors can be caught and handled by your program. "

But on the other hand,if it refers to java Errors then they are internal errors.

So is that statement is exactly true or false?

Comment: 21 days seriously?? :-)

Comment: An `Error` is not an `Exception` at all. An `Error` extends directly from `Throwable` and is unchecked. And references to **errors** shouldn't be confused with the java type `Error`.

Answer (score 6):

The best place for such explanations is the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html). 
`Throwable` is the super class, under which there is `Error` and `Exception`.
`RuntimeException` is a subclass under `Exception`.

- `Error` & its sub-classes are unchecked.
- `Exception` & its sub-classes are checked;

  - except for the `RuntimeException` branch.

The difference between the `Error` and `RuntimeException` classes are that

- `Error` isn't in your control. They're usually some system/environment issue; e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`.
- `RuntimeException` on the other hand represent a flaw in the logic of your program, i.e. it's in your control. You can correct it. E.g. `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks  very much for the answer:) I do know the hierarchy of throwable,what I'm confused with is  (Unchecked exceptions== runtime exceptions) part? Errors are also Unchecked exceptions as I've taught!

Comment: Yes, you're right. Both `Error` & `RuntimeException` are unchecked exceptions.

Comment: So is "Unchecked exceptions, also called runtime exceptions" wrong? because runtime exceptions are just a subset of unchecked exceptions and not equivalent terms.

Comment: Well, it depends on the context. We know that there is nothing we can do if we encounter an `Error`. So, there isn't much talk about it. So, the only  unchecked exceptions we're interested are the `RuntimeException`. That's why, many simply generalize - unchecked exceptions aka run-time exceptions. But if you want to get technical, then yes, it would be wrong. Unchecked exceptions can be either of `Error` or `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Ah,it clarifies the confusion I had :)

Answer (score 1):

Error should not be caught because it's caused by a serious problem.
RuntimeException are thrown only at runtime and the compiler does not complain when you do not put fence the code that could throw them.
Checked exception should be caught or send the exception at the calling level

Answer (score 0):

A Runtime exception doesn't need to have a try-catch block, nor does the constructor or method need a `throws` statement.

The [docs page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) from oracle does some good explaining.